# Web scraping 2020 data from IPL website. Getting an IndexError

Tags: python, web-scraping

Can someone please help me proceed with this web scraping of IPL 2020 data?
My code is as follows:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

scrape_url="https://www.iplt20.com/stats/2020/most-runs"
page_connect = urlopen(scrape_url)
page_connect

page_html=BeautifulSoup(page_connect, 'html.parser')

page_html.findAll(name='div class="js-table"')

json_raw_string= page_html.findAll(name='div class="js-table"')[0].string
json_raw_string
```

I'm getting an error- IndexError: list index out of range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means there is no element that it finds from `page_html.findAll(name='div class="js-table"')`

Also, when you say `.string`, are you looking for the text of the element? If so, use `.text`

If you are looking for a div with a certain class, I would recommend using the class_ attribute of `findAll`, e.g. `page_html.findAll('div', class_='js-table')`

If you only need the first element from the list of found elements, you can replace `findAll` with `find`, so you would have

```py
json_raw_string = page_html.find('div', class_='js-table').text
```

---

To make this a dataframe, you can use `pandas.read_html` like so:

```py
table_holder = page_html.find('div', class_='js-table')  # the div element that has the table
table_html = str(table_holder.find('table'))  # find the table, turn it into a raw string of the html

# get your dataframe
df = pd.read_html(table_html)[0]  # read_html returns a list of dataframes, in this case it only has one dataframe in it
```

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful. Sorry to bother you but could you also tell me the indices to take for the string to proceed from here?

Comment: How do you want the data to look?

Comment: In a DataFrame, so that I can run regression on it.

Comment: Anyone? Please help me with it

Comment: Hey! Sorry for the late reply! I edited my answer to include how to do this